# How to access error reason in Python google.cloud.storage upload methods?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I am using Google's `google-cloud-storage` Python package for GCS access.  When I get a 403 error it could be for many different reasons.  Google's SDK by default only provides this message:

```
('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)")
```

Using a debugger I can look deeper into the library and find `_upload.py` has a `_process_response` method where the true HTTP response can be found, with the following message as part of the result:

```
"message": "$ACCOUNT does not have storage.objects.delete access to $BLOB."
```

---

**Q: Is there any way I can access this more useful error code or the raw response?**

I am hoping to present to the user the difference between e.g. expired credentials and attempting to do something your credentials do not allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of `google-cloud-storage` are you using? With the latest, and this example:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service-account.json')
bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket-name')
blob = bucket.get_blob('test.txt')
try:
    blob.delete()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

It prints the following:

> `403 DELETE https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket-name/o/test.txt?generation=1579627133414449: $ACCOUNT does not have storage.objects.delete access to my-bucket-name/test.txt.`

The string representation here is roughly the same as `e.message`:

```
>>> e.message
'DELETE https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket-name/o/test.txt?generation=1579627133414449: $ACCOUNT does not have storage.objects.delete access to my-bucket-name/test.txt.'
```

If you want more structure, you can use `e._response.json()`:

```
>>> e._response.json()
{
    'error': {
        'code': 403,
        'message': '$ACCOUNT does not have storage.objects.delete access to my-bucket-name/test.txt/test.txt.',
        'errors': [{
            'message': '$ACCOUNT does not have storage.objects.delete access to my-bucket-name/test.txt/test.txt.',
            'domain': 'global',
            'reason': 'forbidden'
        }]
    }
}
```